# How to add a main method to a static library project?

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4.3

I've got a C++ project in XCode that builds a static library. I'd like to add a main method to the project to allow me to test some of the code in the library.

In an attempt to do this, I first duplicated the project's target, and I then added a main method to this second target (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3321390/765287)). When I build and run this new target, however, my main method doesn't execute.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: this makes no sense.  do you want to add a method to a static library?  or do you want to test the library?

Comment: I want to test part of the library. That's the only reason I'd be adding a main method.  Is this is a crazy idea? Should I look into using some kind of test framework or something instead?  (I'm new to C++ and XCode.)

Comment: why don't you just create an app that links to your library?  you can add main to the library, but it still won't be executable.. it's just a library.  now you see why it doesn't make sense?  adding main to the library doesn't let you test it, so the two things you're trying to do are totally independent.

Comment: I get it. Thanks!   When I work in Java, I sometimes add a (temporary) main method to a class as a quick, informal way of testing its behaviour. I guess that's not done in C++. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @dB' I have the same problem. I want to use a small piece of code to quickly  get some insight of a vast library. In java you can add a main and debug line by line and quickly make sense of a lot of things. The answer below is not really helpful for such case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical way to test a library is that you write a separate piece of code that exercises the libary, and compares the result with expected results.

In this case, the `main` will go into the test program, not the library. Having a `main` in the library is not the right thing, and will lead to very curious problems for the user of the library if the user forgets to supply a `main`...